# PhpStorm intellisense not working for TypeScript code distributed via NPM

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, npm, phpstorm, intellisense

I have two NPM modules, let's call them **A** and **B**.

Both written in TypeScript. Both compiles into CommonJS Node-like modules.

Module **B** depends on module **A**, so I install in with `npm install --save A`. It have been properly installed into `node_modules/A` folder.

Then in my new module **B** I want to use class `Class` from module **A**. So I write:

```
// import Class from 'A/lib/Class'; <- This import statement must be suggested by PhpStorm

export default class NewClass extends Class {
    // boring implementation details
}
```

The problem is **PhpStorm** (version 2016.3.2) does not suggest to add any import statement like it does for local project files. TypeScript Service says that class name not found and PhpStorm only suggests to rename class `Class`.

Is there any possibility to say PhpStorm to give me suggestions, code completition for modules written in TypeScript and distributed via NPM?

I think the number of TypeScript modules grows over time and it's much easier in TypeScript projects to use TypeScript code directly from modules, without .d.ts files.

Comment: The import name would probably not be "A/lib/Class". It would be whatever you exported it from. What does the `main` key of the A package look like? That will point to the main module. It would be something like `import Class from "A"` or `import { Class } from "A"`, or some other variation, depending on how you exported it. A link to the npm package or its repository would also help so people can investigate it better.

Comment: Module A is a library of classes. For example class `Transition` placed in file `lib/UI/Animation/Transition.ts` under A module and exported as `default`. Inside module B I import it using `import Transition from 'A/lib/UI/Animation/Transition';`. And PhpStorm does not suggest to import this file automatically, i must write imports myself.

Comment: @zeh, is there any possibility to say PhpStorm to give me suggestions, code completition for modules written in TypeScript and distributed via NPM? As I understood, PhpStorm does not index _node_modules_ folder by default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution.

If you want to distribute TypeScript modules via NPM and have advantages of IDE intellisense, you need to set `compilerOptions.declaration` to `true` in youe `tsconfig` file. This will say TS compiler to generate `d.ts` definitions for each `.ts` file. In dependent modules IDE will properly suggest you to import files is some of types are not resolved in your code.